# scrapyd-deploy error: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, scrapyd

I have been trying for a long time to find a solution to the scrapyd error message: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'idna<3,>=2.5' distribution was not found and is required by requests

What I have done:

`$ docker pull ceroic/scrapyd`
`$ docker build -t scrapyd .`

**Dockerfile:**

FROM ceroic/scrapyd
RUN pip install "idna==2.5"

`$ docker build -t scrapyd .`
Sending build context to Docker daemon  119.3kB 
Step 1/2 : FROM ceroic/scrapyd 
---> 868dca3c4d94
Step 2/2 : RUN pip install "idna==2.5"
---> Running in c0b6f6f73cf1
Downloading/unpacking idna==2.5
Installing collected packages: idna
Successfully installed idna
Cleaning up...
Removing intermediate container c0b6f6f73cf1
---> 849200286b7a
Successfully built 849200286b7a
Successfully tagged scrapyd:latest

**I run the container:**
`$ docker run -d -p 6800:6800 scrapyd`
**Next:**
`scrapyd-deploy demo -p tutorial`
**And get error**:
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'idna<3,>=2.5' distribution was not found and is required by requests

I'm not a Docker expert, and I don't understand the logic. If idna==2.5 has been successfully installed inside the container, why does the error message require version 'idna<3,>=2.5'?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. I finished my 3 days! torment. When I run the
`scrapyd-deploy demo -p tutorial` 
then I do it not in the created container, but outside it.

The problem was solved by:
`pip uninstall idna`
`pip install "idna == 2.5"`

This was to be done on a virtual server, not a container. I can't believe I didn't understand it right away.